# Mi primer programa en python no funciona como quisiera. Dónde está mi fallo?

Tags: python

## Soyunordenador.py

```
print("Hola, me llamo Bernat y soy un ordenador del 1532, ¿Cómo te llamas?")
Sunombre = input()
print("¿Cuántos años tienes?")
Suedad = input()
print("¿Sabías que tu nombre tiene", str(len(Sunombre)), "letras y yo soy", str(486-int(Lasevaedat)), "años mayor que tu?")
Sino = input ()
if (Sino ==("sí" or "si" or "Sí" or "Si" or "SÍ" or "SI")):
    print("Uauuuuuu!!....Eres un gran matemático, mucho gusto de conocerte, espero nos volvamos a ver")
if (Sino ==("NO" or "No" or "no")):
    print("No pasa nada, las mates se aprenden con el tiempo, hasta pronto") 
print ("Gusto de conocerte")
```

Comment: De preferncia que expliques mas la pregunta o la edites y muestres cual fue el error que te da

Comment: ¿Donde declaras "Lasevaedat"? porque la usas para responder al usuario pero no aparece en tu código

Comment: Es que el programa anteriormente estaba en catalán y lo he traducido al castellano. Pero con las prisas me olvidé traducirlo. Debería poner Suedad. Si pongo Suedad tampoc funciona como me gustaría.

Comment: Entiende no podemos saber "como te gustaría" que funcione el programa si no lo explicas. Lo que si te pudo decirte es que los dos `if` no son válidos para lo que supongo intentas hacer, deberías hacer algo así: `if Sino in ["sí","si","Sí","Si","SÍ","SI"]:`

Answer (score 2):

Los condicionales están mal planteados. En `if Sino ==("NO" or "No" or "no"):` (y en el anterior condicional igual) primero se evalúa `("NO" or "No" or "no")`, lo cual es siempre `"NO"` ya que una cadena no vacía siempre se evalúa como verdadera. Por lo tanto, si la entrada es "no", "No" o "nO" no se va a evaluar como cierta.

El condicional debe ser:

```
if Sino == "NO" or Sino == "No" or Sino == "no"
```

ó usando un contenedor y el operador `in`:

```
if Sino in ("NO", "No", "no")
```

Para no tener que comprobar todas las posibilidades de mayúsculas-minúsculas puedes usar `str.lower` para convertir todos los caracteres de la entrada en minúscula y simplificar la comparación:

```
if Sino.lower() == "no":
```

Además de esto, unas observaciones.

- `input` puede recibir una cadena a imprimir antes de esperar la entrada del usuario, lo cual puede simplificar el código al prescindir de muchos de los `print`.
- No uses dos `if`, si el primero se cumple no tiene sentido evaluar el segundo. En su lugar usa `elif`.
- Por convención, los nombres de las variables no debe empezar con mayúscula y debe separarse las palabras usando `_`. Son solo convenciones, pero ayudan a la legibilidad y estandarización del código.

Con todo esto, puedes hacer:

```
su_nombre = input("Hola, me llamo Bernat y soy un ordenador del 1532, "
                  "¿Cómo te llamas? ")
su_edad = input("\n¿Cuántos años tienes? ")
resp = input("¿Sabías que tu nombre tiene {} letras y yo soy {} años mayor que tu? "
             .format(len(su_nombre), 486-int(su_edad)))

if resp.lower() in ("sí", "si"):
    print("Uauuuuuu!!....Eres un gran matemático, mucho gusto de conocerte, "
          "espero nos volvamos a ver")
elif resp.lower() == "no":
    print("No pasa nada, las mates se aprenden con el tiempo, hasta pronto")
else:
     print("No he entendido tu respuesta...")

print ("Gusto de conocerte")
```

Puedes usar `str.format` para formatear la cadena en vez de concatenar (lo cual es muy ineficiente dado que las cadenas son inmutables). Si usas Python 3.6 en adelante son más eficeintes y simples los literales de cadena formateados.

```
resp = input(f"¿Sabías que tu nombre tiene {len(su_nombre)} letras y "
             f"yo soy {486-int(su_edad)} años mayor que tu? ")
```

Comment: Sugiero que anotes en la respuesta que cambiaste la variable de su_edad que esta en la respuesta

Comment: wow. Menuda respuesta! Muchisimas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

La excelente respuesta de FJSevilla te explica sucintamente por qué no funciona y cómo arreglarlo.

Sólo quería añadir una explicación un poco más detallada de por qué:

```
if (Sino ==("NO" or "No" or "no")):
```

funcionaría cuando el usuario responda "NO", pero no funcionaría si responde "No" o "no".

Entiendo que pretendías que el `if` se ejecutara si la respuesta era cualquiera de las tres, pero no es eso lo que estás expresando. Lo que estás expresando es que se ejecute el `if` cuando la variable `Sino` sea igual al resultado de evaluar la expresión `("NO" or "No" or "no")`. Hay que explicar por tanto cómo evalúa python una expresión así.

Cuando python se encuentra varias expresiones separadas por `or`, lo que hace es examinar el valor de verdad de la primera de ellas. Si es considerada verdad, ya no mira las restantes (pues en el `or` basta que una sea verdad para que la expresión completa lo sea). El resultado de la expresión completa es igual al valor de su primer expresión antes del `or`. Si la primera expresión antes del primer `or` fuera considerada falsa, entonces se miraría la siguiente, etc.

En definitiva, el resultado de una expresión como `(A or B or C)` es `A` si `A` se considera verdadera, o `B` si `A` se considera falsa pero `B` verdadera, o `C` si `A` y `B` se consideran falsas, pero `C` verdadera, o `C` si las tres se consideran falsas.

Ahora bien, si `A` es un booleano, está claro lo que significa que `A` sea verdadera o falsa. Pero si `A` es de otro tipo ¿qué se considera falso o verdadero? Depende del tipo:

- Si `A` es un entero (o un flotante), se considera falso si vale 0 (ó 0.0), y verdadero si es distinto de cero.
- Si `A` es una cadena, se considera falsa si es la cadena vacía `""` y verdadera en caso contrario.
- Si `A` es una lista (o un contenedor) se considera falsa si está vacía  (`[]`) y verdadera en caso contrario.
- etc. Cada tipo tiene un caso en que se considera falso y otros en que se considera verdadero.

En tu ejemplo `A` sería la cadena `"NO"`. Esa cadena no está vacía, por lo que se considera verdadera. Por tanto la expresión `("NO" or "No" or "no")` se evalúa y su resultado es `"NO"`. Por consiguente tu `if` equivale a:

```
if (Sino =="NO"):
```

y por eso no funciona como esperabas. Otro tanto ocurre con el `if` del "si".

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Estaba buscando una respuesta que tenía por ahí explicando lo del valor boleano asociado a cada objeto para asociarla pero tu respuesta cubre con creces lo que dejé un poco suelto en cuanto a explicación en la mía, así que lo dejo así ツ.